# Usar un parametro en URL para ciertos estados en el inicio de la misma

Tags: angularjs

Estoy usando [angular router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) para trabajar en mi sitio. Ahora mismo un requisito del sistema es mantener un elemento que es crucial para el sitio en la URL pero para que sea una URL semántica, necesito que ese elemento esté al inicio de toda la URL, mucho antes de estar definiendo la URL del estado.

Ahora mismo mis estados se ven así:

```
'secure': {
    name: 'Secure',
    url: '/secure',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
      '@': {
        templateUrl: './views/common/layout.html'
      },
      'header@secure': {
        templateUrl: './views/common/header.html'
      },
      'navigation@secure': {
        templateUrl: './views/common/navigation.html'
      },
      'footer@secure': {
        templateUrl: './views/common/footer.html'
      }
    }
  },
  'secure.manageFeatures': {
    'name': 'manageFeatures',
    'url': '/manageFeatures',
    'templateUrl': './views/manageFeatures.html',
    'data': {
      'pageTitle': 'manageFeatures'
    }
  },
  'secure.technicalConfiguration': {
    name: 'configuration',
    url: '/configuration',
    templateUrl: './views/technicalConfiguration.html',
    controller: 'secTechnicalConfigurationCtrl',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Configuration'
    }
  }
```

Y las url lucen así:

http://localhost:9000/#/secure/manageFeatures
http://localhost:9000/#/secure/technicalConfiguration

Necesito hacer que las URL tengan un parámetro mas al inicio y no en todas las URL.

Por ejemplo:

http://localhost:9000/#/550862/secure/manageFeatures
http://localhost:9000/#/secure/technicalConfiguration

He intentado usar la mismo documentación ofrecida y colocando el param al final de la URL

```
url: '/configuration/:idCuenta'
```

Funciona perfecto, pero al hacerlo al contrario no funciona correctamente, ya que tendría que modificar el estado padre de todos "secure" y no podría controlar cuando necesitar el id y cuando no usarlo.

En angular ya he trabajado mucho tiempo pero soy nuevo usando ui router. Agradezco no ser muy estrictos con mis preguntas.

Comment: Tengo unas dudas, ¿Por que necesitas/quieres armar la URL de esa forma?, es decir, ¿que _semantica_ (como dices) agrega tener este ID en esa ubicación? y ¿exactamente de que entidad es dicho ID?, Las preguntas son pues lo mas intuitivo es que el ID este después del nombre de la entidad.

Comment: Es la cuenta a la que se le están haciendo los cambios. Todo el sistema trabaja sobre cuentas pero hay ciertos elementos que son por usuario y esas son las que el id no debe ir.

Comment: En ese caso, ¿por que no usar un esquema `/account/:cuenta/secure/etc` y `/user/secure/src`... Podrias reutilizar los controladores aunque utilices mas rutas?

Comment: La solución es simple. Usa los parámetros al final o en el medio pero nunca al principio de tus urls, de lo contrario te va a resultar muy complicado diseñar tu aplicación. No hay necesidad de agregar complejidad innecesaria.